# How to safely remove a module from another module's "imports"

Tags: angular

I have a module "A" that imports another module "B".

I want to remove module B from module A's imports list.

Both are big modules, and I don't have tests there.

Is there a way to make sure nothing's using it? (for example trying to render a component from module B in module A)

Comment: I suspect you’ll get some errors when you try to serve the app? Just solve those one by one?